# Image path for displaying on a user profile

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have managed to find the code I needed but just have some questions that need answering so that I understand as I am a little confused. I understand that the below code allows me to upload an image but what I cant get my head around is how i would display the image for a profile picture, by this I mean what path would I use to locate the image for the individual user. I just need this explaining to me so that I understand it

Many Thanks the code I am using for uploading the image is below

```
<!--- set the full path to the images folder --->
<cfset mediapath = expandpath('./images')>

<!--- set the desired image height ---->
<cfset thumbsize = 75>

<!--- set the desired image width --->
<cfset imagesize = 320>


<cfif structKeyExists(form,"fileUpload") and len(form.fileUpload)>
   <cffile action="upload"
   filefield="FileUpload"
   destination="#MediaPath#"
   nameconflict="makeunique">

   <!--- read the image ---->
   <cfimage name="uploadedImage"
   source="#MediaPath#/#file.serverFile#" >

   <!--- figure out which way to scale the image --->
   <cfif uploadedImage.width gt uploadedImage.height>
         <cfset thmb_percentage = (thumbsize / uploadedImage.width)>
         <cfset percentage = (imagesize / uploadedImage.width)>
      <cfelse>
         <cfset thmb_percentage = (thumbsize / uploadedImage.height)>
         <cfset percentage = (imagesize / uploadedImage.height)>
   </cfif>

   <!--- calculate the new thumbnail and image height/width --->
   <cfset thumbWidth = round(uploadedImage.width * thmb_percentage)>
   <cfset thumbHeight = round(uploadedImage.height * thmb_percentage)>

   <cfset newWidth = round(uploadedImage.width * percentage)>
   <cfset newHeight = round(uploadedImage.height * percentage)>

   <!--- see if we need to resize the image, maybe it is already smaller than our desired size --->
   <cfif uploadedImage.width gt imagesize>
         <cfimage action="resize"
       height="#newHeight#"
       width="#newWidth#"
       source="#uploadedImage#"
      destination="#MediaPath#/#file.serverFile#"
       overwrite="true"/>
   </cfif>

    <!--- create a thumbnail for the image --->
    <cfimage action="resize"
    height="#thumbHeight#"
    width="#thumbWidth#"
    source="#uploadedImage#"
    destination="#MediaPath#/thumbs/#file.serverFile#"
    overwrite="true"/>

   <cfoutput>
      <img src="images/thumbs/#file.serverFile#" height="#thumbHeight#" width="#thumbWidth#" align="left" hspace="10"><br>

      Original Image: #uploadedImage.width#x#uploadedImage.height#<br>
      Resized Image: #newWidth#x#newHeight#<br>
      Thumbnail: #thumbWidth#x#thumbHeight#<br><br>
      <a href="images/#file.serverFile#">See Image</a><br>

   </cfoutput>
</cfif>   

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="fileUpload">Choose Image: </label>
   <input type="file" name="fileUpload">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

Comment: There is a large security issue with your code.  First, don't upload into a web accessible directory.  Second, there is no clean up procedure if the image processing fails.  So, I could upload a cfm, or  any othe file. Then the image processor would fail, I would then have a cfm I could access on your server that could create all kinds of havoc.

Comment: what would you recommend, Im searching for a good tutorial at the minute

Comment: I would just recommend you up load the file to a non-web accessible temp directory.  Validate the file and change it there.  When done then move it to the perminate location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saving the images to a folder named '/images', so the path would simply be `/images/{file name}`. You would need to make sure that either a) you persist the file name somewhere or 2) you name the file after a piece of information you already have, such as the persons username or id (I would suggest NOT using the id, though)

Comment: ok thats great, so i would basically force the rename of the file to username image, I wouldnt do anything in the database would I or would it be better to look for options that tied that image to the user in the database.

Comment: That is entirely up to you. I would probably store the file name in the database, but you need not do it that way.